# Как работает обновление состояния в игровых движках?

Tags: разработка-игр

У меня появилась идея написать свой игровой движок, по ходу дела сформировались некоторые вопросы

Предположим, вся игра состоит из объектов, у каждого объекта есть функция, вызываемая каждый кадр.
У меня есть два объекта, я хочу чтобы один объект **А** полностью копировал, например, позицию и поворот другого объекта **В**.
Здесь возникает проблема. Если функции обновления объектов вызываются друг за другом последовательно, то объект **А** может отставать от объекта **В** на кадр (если они обновляются в неправильном порядке).
Как решать такое?

Может, сортировать объекты по порядку обновления?
А что если у меня, напрмер, два объекта сталкиваются друг с другом и я хочу вычислить их импульс и поменять позицию основываясь на позиции друг друга? В каком бы я порядке их не обновлял, первое обновление изменит данные и второе произойдет не так как нужно.

Comment: Если логика подразумевает «привязку» одного объекта к другому, то можно изобрести связь родитель-потомок, чтобы потомок A вообще не хранил у себя никаких координат, а при запросе координат просто возвращал координаты своего родителя B

Comment: Уточните какого рода у вас планируются взаимодействия между объектами. Может быть вам нужно обновлять их не по отдельности, а в общем "менеджере".